# Don't allow function to make Tk GUI hang

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter, freeze

so i have a program that is doing the following:

1. connects to my MySQL database and extracts certain table with IP
   addresses
2. store addresses in a list
3. for every IP in list, depeding on a user preference, via sockets, i send or receive files to that IP address

So, lets say i have a send() function, that starts when i press a Button from another function and it does this:

```
for host in IP_list:
    socket.connect((host,5005))...
    socket.send(data)...
```

Now when server is active, code works and everything copies very fast.
However, currently i am working on code polling, and when server is not up, and client cannot connect, code performs rather slow, and GUI hangs (example is when list has 25ish IP-s to which function needs to connect to).

**So what i want to do is** `socket.connect((host,5005))` in another thread (or anything not to hang my GUI)

Now, i tried with threading, but it acts strange. It never works good with tkinter, since besides upper code lines, i have tk.progressbar and few other Tk things in that function.

I have no idea how to do it with multiprocessing, and apparently, it has no effect on IO hangs.

Anybody who can provide me with some ideas?

Here is how i tried with threading:

```
def connect():
    global host
    global socket
    socket.connect((host,5005))


def my_original_function():
    global host
    global socket
    t1=threading.Thread(target=connect)
    for host in IP_list:
        t1.start()
        t1.join()
```

Comment: Can you show us how you tried with threading?

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively simple to start more than one thing in multiprocessing.  I usually stick everything in one class to keep everything connected.  One caveat is to create one TK() class instance only.  More than one causes problems.  time.sleep() is used in the start_running function instead of after() to simulate one thread hanging.  If you are going to use Tkinter and get into more advanced programming, using classes will simplify your life IMHO.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

try:
    import Tkinter as tk    ## Python 2.x
except:
    import tkinter as tk    ## Python 3.x

class ProgressBar():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry("75x50+900+100")
        self.ctr=25

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def start_countdown(self):
        """ a separate process in a separate GUI
        """
        self.root.withdraw()
        self.top_count=tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.top_count.geometry("75x50+750+50")
        self.label_ctr = tk.IntVar()
        self.label_ctr.set(self.ctr)
        label = tk.Label(self.top_count, textvariable=self.label_ctr)
        label.pack()
        if self.ctr > 0:
            self.top_count.after(750, self.update)

    def start_running(self):
        """ create the progress bar widget
        """
        self.top=tk.Toplevel(self.root, takefocus=True)
        self.top.title("Progress Bar")
        self.top.geometry("+700+200")
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.top, width=261, height=60, bg='lightgray')
        canvas.pack()

        rc2 = canvas.create_rectangle(15, 20, 243, 50, outline='blue',                                       fill='lightblue')
        rc1 = canvas.create_rectangle(24, 20, 34, 50, outline='white',                                       fill='blue')

        total=100
        x = 5
        ## only use after() while the countdown is running (self.ctr > 0)
        ## to avoid a dangling after() when the program terminates
        while self.ctr:        ## move the small rectangle +5 or -5 units
            total += x
            if total > 311:
                x = -5
            elif total < 100:
                x = 5
            time.sleep(0.2)
            canvas.move(rc1, x, 0)
            canvas.update()

    def update(self):
        self.ctr -= 1
        self.label_ctr.set(self.ctr)

        if self.ctr > 0:
            self.top_count.after(750, self.update)
        else:
            ## sleep to allow any remaining after() to execute
            ## can also use self.root.after_cancel(id)
            self.top_count.after(500, self.root.destroy) ## destroy root when ctr==0

root = tk.Tk()

PB=ProgressBar(root)
pr1=Process(target=PB.start_countdown(), args=())
pr1.start()

pr2=Process(target=PB.start_running(), args=())
pr2.start()

## start mainloop in a separate process as a function of the class
## don't know if this is really necessary or not
## the theory is, it is detached from the other 2 processes and so
##    can react to both independently
## also the mainloop() process can be killed=shut down properly
pr3=Process(target=PB.mainloop(), args=())
pr3.start()

## safety clean up
pr1.terminate()
pr2.terminate()
pr3.terminate()
```